# How to setup a VLAN that spans across both Hp 1810g and hp 2920G

Tags: vlan

I am trying to setup a tagged vlan that spans across both  Hp 1810g and hp 2920G. I have setup a trunk and tagged it on both sides but I fail to see an machine on the tagged vlan. I see the untagged vlan across the switches fine. Any help would be great.

```
On the Hp 2920G

  ID 1 Default VLAN
  Untagged Ports 1-23 Trk1

  ID 9 PRIVLAN
  Tagged(Static) Ports 1-23 Trk1

On the HP 1810g

  ID 1 Default VLAN
  Untagged Ports 2-4 Trk1

  ID 9 PRIVLAN 
  Tagged Ports 2-4 Trk1
  Untagged Port 5
```

There is a server on Port 5 of the HP 1810g and there many clients on Hp 2920G and  HP 1810g but they will only see the server if they have the vlan 9 setup. This setup works on HP 1810g but would like to expand it to the other client on Hp 2920G. But it is not working on the Hp 2920G, clients can't see the server.

Comment: It would help if you provided the configuration of your ports.  However, for your new VLAN are the ports configured to use that VLAN untagged rather than your first VLAN?

Comment: It's really not clear exactly what your issue is. When you say "I fail to see a machine on the tagged vlan", what does that mean? Where are you looking from?

Comment: You have VLAN9 extended from switch to switch, but on the 2920G you have all the client untagged traffic being put in the default VLAN. Either you need to put them in VLAN 9. You can't have clients in both VLAN1 AND VLAN9 - you have two networks. The alternative there is to have a device route between the two networks. The 1810G can't do Layer 3 routing; the 2920G can. You need to, e.g. extend VLAN 1 and 9 to your router/firewall/default gateway and have it route between them.

Comment: I created the configuration that you described below. On vlan9 on  HP 2920 , I have 2 clients with ports untagged for vlan9 and on the 1810G , I have one client on vlan9 on untagged port. The trunk is tagged vlan9 on both switches. I tried the trunk as static and LACP but the client can't see the other client on the other switch. But the 2 client on the one can see each other.

Answer (score 4):

"Trunks" on HP switches are link aggregation related, not VLAN related.

VLANs aren't tagged, network traffic is tagged.

- A port "tagged" to handle VLAN 9, will accept network traffic that has a VLAN tag number 9, and pass it from the cable to the switch, or from the switch to the cable, keeping the VLAN tag on it unchanged.
- A port "untagged" in VLAN 9, will accept network traffic that has NO VLAN tag (the default) and put it internally with a VLAN tag of 9, it will also take traffic internally in VLAN 9 and remove the VLAN tag and send it out onto the wire with NO VLAN tag.
- A port "excluded" from VLAN 9 will not pass traffic with a VLAN tag of 9 either way through it.

In HP 1810G switches, you select the VLAN and then set per-interface. On Cisco switches you configure the interface, then set per VLAN. But either way there's no "tagged VLAN" there is only tagged or untagged *traffic* and whether the switch is allowing it, rejecting it, or adding/removing a VLAN tag as it passes from switch to cable.

So to get two things which have no knowledge of VLANs, to connect accross two switches using VLANs to isolate them from other network traffic, you need to have, e.g.

```
Server -> HP 1810G port 4
Choose VLAN 9. Set port 4 for "untagged" meaning accept traffic from the cable 
with no tag and add a VLAN tag 9, send traffic out from VLAN 9 but strip the tag.

HP 1810G port 24 <--> HP 2920 port 24
Choose VLAN 9 on both switches. Set port 24 as "tagged" so both switches pass 
traffic with VLAN tag 9 between them, without changing the tag.

HP 2920G port 4 -> workstation.
HP 2920G choose VLAN 9, set port 4 "untagged" so it allows internal traffic 
on VLAN 9 to pass, but it strips the VLAN tag from outgoing traffic and adds 
it to incoming traffic.
```

The workstation and server will connect through VLAN 9, over the link between switches.

Comment: I added my configuration above, your configuration is close. I am starting to think it might be the setup of the trunk some how. On the HP 2920 I have GVRP disbaled, STP Disabled, LACP Status Disabled, and Trunk type Trunk not LACP, Flow Control Disabled.  Then on the  HP 1810g static capability is on and everything else seems to be off.

Comment: Trunking is for link aggregation, why are you configuring a trunk with one port and then disabling link aggregation? You don't need a HP "Trunk" to connect two switches, you just need a patch lead.

Comment: I am just learning this stuff but would like to use link aggregation once I get this problem resolved. Want to use 2 cables between switches.